# What does "argument sharing" mean in terms of co-ordination?

Tags: clauses, coordination, transitivity, argument

According to my professor, argument sharing under co-ordination only seems possible when an argument in the transitive is in ABS or NOM. What is meant by `argument sharing`? Could you give an example?